# DataTables editable cant figure out how to delete/update rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables, server-side

I am trying to implement dataTables plugin in server-side mode to render a table on my  webpage. I am coding ASP.NET with c# and MVC.

I want to edit (delete/update/add) data to the table and write any change to my database.
But in difference to the example of this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165410/ASP-NET-MVC-Editable-DataTable-jQuery-DataTables-a data provided by my controller does not contain a single primary key, but a compound key:

- projectId and
- questionId

Here's my controller, which provides data from my database:

```
public ActionResult AjaxHandler(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
    {

        var any = (from pq in _db.ProjectQuestions
                   join q in _db.Question
                   on pq.QuestionID equals q.QuestionID
                   join c in _db.Category
                   on q.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID
                   select new
                   { 
                       projectID = pq.ProjectID,
                       questionID = q.QuestionID,                           
                       categoryName = c.CategoryName,
                       questionName = q.QuestionName,
                       questionDescription = q.QuestionDescription
                   });

        int count = any.Count();
        var result = new List<object[]>();

        return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = param.sEcho,
            iTotalRecords = count,
            iTotalDisplayRecords = count,
            aaData = any
        },
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

So far the standard DeleteData/UpdateData and AddData methods dont even receive any value for id.

```
public string DeleteData(int id)
        {
            return "ok";
}
```

How can I use the CRUD-functionality of Editable if my data has to be identified by two parameters?

So far I couldn't find any solution to edit data. Many thanks in advance.
_tek

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Grid view function.

Please follow this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZIOI136IKY